# Find first occurrence of a small sequence from a long list in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, spreadsheet

I have a long list of words in separate cells in a row
in an Excel spreadsheet. 
For example

```
   A      B      C      D      E      F      G
blue   red    yellow blue   green  red    purple ...
```

I want to find where (in what columns) a particular sequence of words
(e.g., `orange`,`red`,`blue`) happens first in the list.

---

**Possibly Better Example:**

The cells contain

```
heads  tails  tails  heads  heads  tails  tails  ...
```

and I want to find where the sequence `heads`,`heads`,`tails` was first found.

Comment: Is it always groups of three.

Comment: Your question is too ambiguous.  Are the names a comma-delimited list in a cell?  Contained in separate cells in a row?  In separate cells in a column?  Do the names contain multiple words, like first and last name separated by a space?  Is "A,B,C" a literal representation of the form?  What do you mean by where it happens first (character position, cell, name index)?  Please add a mock-up of some sample data, a sample search string, and the results you expect.

Comment: Example: a list of names in a row (name 'big_list'): a,b,b,a,c,b,a,a,c.... in separate cells
and the small sequence i need to find (name 'small_list'): a,b,c where in the big_list this was found first.

Comment: What excel are you using? If you are using Office 365 Excel then: `=SEARCH(CONCAT(small_list),CONCAT(big_list))`

Comment: A better example: 
big_list: heads,tails,tails,heads,heads,tails,tails... randomly...... in separate cells in a row.
small_list: heads,heads,tails
Need to find where heads,heads,tails was first found in big_list.

Comment: @ScottCraner: But `CONCATENATE` doesn't work on lists.

Comment: @G-Man not concatenate. In office 365 excel there is a new function CONCAT() which will do what I proposed. As per my previous comment stated.